# local a = true print(a and false or true) why result always be true whether a==false or a == true?

Tags: lua

Why is a not correct?
I can't understand.

Code:

```
C:\Users\Administrator>lua53
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> local a = true print(a and false or true)
true
> local a = false print(a and false or true)
true
> local a = false print(a == true and false or true)
true
> local a = true print(a == true and false or true)
true
> local a = true print(a == false and false or true)
true
> local a = false print(a == false and false or true)
true
> local a = false print((a == false) and false or true)
true
> local a = false print(not a )
true
> local a = true print(not a )
false
>
```

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Or other text. Post the actual text. And the code that generated it.

Comment: local a = true print(a == true and false or true)   ,and the result is true,I think it must be false.  so I change the codes to be : local a = true,print(not a ),then it's correct !

Comment: Your question is still unclear. What about this do you not understand?

Comment: `a = 1;
 print(tostring(a == 1 and true or (a == 2 and true or (a == true or a <= 3 and true or false))));

 -- will print true if
 -- a == 1
 -- a == 2
 -- a == 3
 -- a == true`

will print false for everything else

Answer (score 1):

In Lua, `and` and `or` have the [*lowest* operator precedence](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.8), with `or` being lower than `and`. Therefore, any expression of the form `X and false or true` will be interpreted as `(X and false) or true`.

Well, anything logically and-ed with `false` is *false*; that's how logical and works. And anything logically or-ed with `true` is true. And since `or` comes last, all of those expressions are just over-complicated ways of saying `true`.

Comment: But I input 'local a = false  print(a and true or false)'  the result is false.I still don't understand it.

Comment: What part do you not understand? Do you not understand how logical "and" and "or" work? Do you not understand how expressions compose themselves? Which part of that doesn't make sense to you? Boil down each step of the expression to its simplest form and walk through it step by step.